# Using pandas on a CSV file, how do I filter a data set by "month" if the "date" column is in format "MM/DD/YYYY"

Tags: pandas, filtering

I have a CSV file with a column "date" whose values are formatted MM/DD/YYYY. I was wondering if there was a way I could filter the data in this file based on just month using pandas in python.

```
### csv file ###
___, Date,   ...
     12/4/2003
     6/15/2012    
#################


data = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

# how do i do this line? 
is_data_july = data["date"].onlyCheckFirstChar == "6"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

```py
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], ...)
mask = df['date'].dt.month == 6
df.loc[mask].to_csv("newfile.csv")
```

In fact, `pd.read_csv` has a shortcut for this (if the default options in `pd.to_datetime` work for you):

```py
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", parse_dates=['date'])
mask = df['date'].dt.month == 6
df.loc[mask].to_csv("newfile.csv")
```