# How to extract last 1year and 6months data from a .txt into two separate .txt files delimited by '\t'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `data.txt` file which has 3 columns delimited by tab (`'\t'`).The first column has date.

I want to extract data from this file into two separate `.txt` files without changing the original format, such that the 1st file (`first.txt`) contains the data of year 2020, and the 2nd file (`2nd.txt`) contains the last 6 months (June to December) of data for the  year 2020.

Can someone please help with some hints?

[image]

My attempt:

```
first=pd.read_csv('data.txt', parse_dates=True)['2020':]
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far that is not working for you?

Comment: Hi, i have tried: first=pd.read_csv('data.txt', parse_dates=True)['2020':]

Comment: @RemyLebeau can you please suggest a way handle this?

Comment: @johnjohn how to create sub-sets based on column 'date'?

Comment: Tried this as well but not working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55945612/using-pandas-on-a-csv-file-how-do-i-filter-a-data-set-by-month-if-the-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\t', parse_dates=True) #load

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, infer_datetime_format=True) #convert to date if needed

first = df[df['date'].dt.year == 2020] #subset; note you might use other criteria here
second = df[df['date'].dt.year < 2020]
```

EDIT

Following your comment, here's mock data so that you can test the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date': ['05-10-2020', '06-07-2020', '06-12-2019'],
    'test' : ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    'thingy': ['re', 'rho', 'rha']
})
df
```

Note your original data is still in `df`.

You might also define date as index, and then subset:

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True) #set index
```

Subset and save:

```
first = df.loc['2020-01-01':'2020-06-30'] #specify date range
second = df.loc['2020-07-01':'2020-12-31']
```

Comment: Error in the 2nd line: DataFrame object has no attribute 'date'.

Comment: Thank you. When converting  .txt to csv using pd.read_csv() automatically inserts an index column. It will impact when I connvert csv to  .txt. The purpose is to convert  .txt to csv, extract year 2020 and 2nd half of year 2020 and save these in the original format of. txt seperated by tab

Comment: Thanks man. 'first' is working fine. In second, i want to extract data for June, July, August, September, October, November and December for year 2020. Is there a way to put conditions on year and lsit of months both simultaneously

Comment: Yes, you can set the date as the index, and then subset. See updated answer. Happy coding